# How to use auto translate feature of YouTube via YouTube API when adding new subtitles

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

E.g. Video : https://youtu.be/jHTkVm2mcfs

When I go here I can add subtitles like below

https://studio.youtube.com/video/jHTkVm2mcfs/translations

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

My main English Subtitle is a perfectly manually written one. So I want to add subtitles for all languages via automated way.

I asked GPT4 but it says API do not have this feature. Is that accurate?